# Python не работает - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python

Запускаю я свой код и вижу вот это:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Python runtime state: core initialized

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001790 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

В интернете про эту ошибку я ничего не нашёл. Она появляется и в Visual Studio, и в Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Какую версию питона ставили? Погуглил ошибку и такие варианты: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405455/ Если просто, то если используются виртуальные окружения питона, то почистить папку venv. Если нет, то переустановить питон и при установке поставить флаг на установку в переменные среды

Comment: Переустановка не помогает, я уже пробовал.

Comment: Версия Питона - 3.8.

Comment: `print("Hello World!")` - вот этот код

Comment: @Misha добавьте данную инфу в сам вопрос, для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1373304/edit) под самим вопросом. Комментарии после этого можете удалить

Comment: Как/куда установлен Python?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема решается переустановкой Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184937/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-file